# URL reversing not working in django when using arguments

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm really stuck with this one.

I have the following in my urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^user/$', UserView.as_view(), name='farmauth-user'),
url(r'^user/(?P<id>\d+)/confirm/(?P<token>\w+)/$', UserConfirmationView.as_view(), name='farmauth-confirm'),
```

I have other URLs too. Then in my HTML I get

```
Reverse for 'farmauth-confirm' with arguments '([u'28'], [u'n48DsSASbKhabWXzZ6XV'])' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

When I do this:

```
{% url 'farmauth-confirm' id token %}
```

I also tried using positional arguments. In case you are wondering, the URLs are visible where I'm attempting this because this works:

```
{% url 'farmauth-user' %}
```

I tried other URLs with and without arguments. It never works when using arguments. What am I doing wrong??

Please advise.

Comment: That moment I spend hours trying to figure it out, as soon as I make the post I get it right -.-;

When passing the arguments to my view I was doing this:

 return render(request, 'confirm.html', dict(self.get_form_context(), **request.GET))

It seams that GET arguments are arrays, so the token and ID where given as [id] and [token]. Now I do this:

 kwargs = {
  'id': request.GET.get('id'),
  'token': request.GET.get('token'),
 }
 
 return render(request, 'confirm.html', dict(self.get_form_context(), **kwargs))

And it works.

Comment: I can't post as answer yet. I'll do it later.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out, but your url has type `integer` for id, but the url is evaluating `id` as a unicode. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just try another order:

url(r'^user/(?P\d+)/confirm/(?P\w+)/$', UserConfirmationView.as_view(), name='farmauth-confirm'),
url(r'^user/$', UserView.as_view(), name='farmauth-user'),